# How to include '<' as text between html tags?

Tags: html

How can I achieve something simple as this in HTML ?

```
<a href="#"><< Back to Main Page</a>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to [HTML encode](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/htmlencode/encode.aspx) it:

```
<a href="#">&lt;&lt; Back to Main Page</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<a href="#">&lt;&lt; Back to Main Page</a>
```

Comment: @DamienJoe I was the first who gave you the answer. you should have checked myne.

Answer (score 4):

http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/special.html

SO: `&lt;`

-->

```
<a href="#">&lt;&lt; Bla Bla</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

The double chevron is called `&laquo;` for left and `&raquo;` for right.

```
<a href="#">&laquo; Back to Main Page</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

use HTML encode chars `&gt; &lt;`

Answer (score 2):

Use an entity: `&lt;`. Others used often for similar cases is `&laquo;` («).

Answer (score 1):

You can use it.

```
<a href="#"> &#60&#60 Back to Main Page</a>
```